# how to get text attribute from a asp:panel

Tags: c#, asp.net, panel

Probably a simple question, but I've been browsing now for 30 mins and STILL cant find a solution!

i have a panel and it has an attribute text="something". but the panel class does not seem to have a getAttribute method... Which personally, I think is STUPID!

Code follows:

```
foreach (Control c in clientGrid.Controls)
{
    if (c.GetType().ToString().Equals("System.Web.UI.WebControls.Panel"))
    {
        /*Something*/ textInsidePanel = ((Panel)c)./*Somthing*/              
    }
}
```

Now i've tried `AttributeCollection text = ((Panel)c).Attributes`;

and

`string text = ((Panel)c).Attributes.toString();`

and other useless things...

This should be really simple! when i inspect element on chrome, I can see the panel, (well the div) and i can see the text attribute right there. and i can see its value! but i want my c# code to have the value to!!

Please Help!

Alex

Comment: Are you setting the attribute in a script, in c#, or in the aspx page?

Comment: the user sets the text value. and on postback, I need to get the value they set

Comment: that's not possible. Attribute values are not transmitted on post-back. If you need to persist something you can use hidden inputs

Answer (score 4, accepted):

if I get you question right - you can use next code

asp part

```
<asp:Panel runat="server" ID="pnl" Text="hello world"></asp:Panel>
```

c# part -

```
string s = pnl.Attributes["Text"];
```

Comment: You know what... I am Soooo Retarded sometimes

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried using an accessor?:

```
string val = YourPanel.Attributes["Text"];
//                                   ^ that's your attribute name
```

That should get the attribute's value **BUT** I'm pretty sure what you are doing isn't possible as attribute values are not persisted between postbacks (at least not when set via a client script). To do that you should use hidden inputs or some other form element.

Answer (score 0):

The Panel control itself doesn't have a text property. But if you access the inner text as a LiteralControl it will work:

```
var panelContent = ((Panel)c).Controls[0] as LiteralControl;
var text = panelContent.Text;
```

Comment: Thanks for the downvote to whoever. Telling me why my answer was wrong would be helpful though.

Comment: User isn't looking for `InnerText`, user is looking for an attribute on the `<div>` element. Does this do that?

Comment: So I probably misunderstood the question. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.